# TS mixin error not match constructor type constraint

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to derive free implementation from implementing abstract functions, much like this.

```
abstract class Movable {
    abstract right(n: number)
    left(n: number) {
      return this.right(-n)
    }
}
class Cursor extends Movable {
    right() { ... }
}
new Cursor().left() // for free from abstract class
```

I'll have more abstract classes like this to implement in Cursor class so I'm using mixins but encountered a type error as shown following, based on [TS mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) example, need some helps, thank you.

```
type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T

interface Navigation<T> {
  up(n: number): Navigation<T>
  down(n: number): Navigation<T>
  left(n: number): Navigation<T>
  right(n: number): Navigation<T>
  move(n: number): Navigation<T>
}

type Movable<T> = GConstructor<{
  right: (n: number) => Navigation<T>
  down: (n: number) => Navigation<T>
}>

function Movable<T, TBase extends Movable<T>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Movable extends Base {
    left(n = 1) {
      return this.right(-n)
    }

    up(n = 1) {
      return this.down(-n)
    }

    move(right = 0, down = 0) {
      this.right(right).down(down)  // <- this function requires right() return Navigation instead of Movable
    }
  }
}

class Cursor {
  row: number = 0
  col: number = 0
  down(n: number) {
    return new CursorNext(this.row + n, this.col)  // <- this feels a little off, but return Cursor has same error
  }

  right(n: number) {
    return new CursorNext(this.row, this.col + n)
  }
}

const CursorNext = Movable<Cursor, Cursor>(Cursor)
                                   ^^^^^^
Type 'Cursor' does not satisfy the constraint 'Movable<Cursor>'.
  Type 'Cursor' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): { right: (n: number) => Navigation<Cursor>; down: (n: number) => Navigation<Cursor>; }'.
```

Comment: WHy do you expect that `class Cursor` has `row` and `col` properties in `this` ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Cursor actually has those properties, I omitted them due do they are not relevant in for this error, you are right I should add them for clarity.

Comment: Try `const CursorNext = Movable<Cursor, CursorNext>(Cursor)`?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your suggestions, I've tried with your suggestions and have errors of `'CursorNext' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here`, then I tried `Movable<Cursor, typeof CursorNext>(Cursor)` it has error `CursorNext used before its declaration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type argument for the `TBase` type parameter is `typeof Cursor`, which would also be inferred if you were to omit it. However, to typecheck that `typeof Cursor` satisfies `Movable<T>`, you will also need to break the circular reference and explicitly declare the return types of the `Cursor.down` and `.right` methods to be compatible with `Navigation`.

```
type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T

interface Navigation<T> {
  up(n: number): Navigation<T>
  down(n: number): Navigation<T>
  left(n: number): Navigation<T>
  right(n: number): Navigation<T>
}

type Movable<T> = {
  right: (n: number) => Navigation<T>
  down: (n: number) => Navigation<T>
}

function Navigable<T, TBase extends GConstructor<Movable<T>>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class extends Base implements Navigation<T> {
    left(n = 1) {
      return this.right(-n)
    }

    up(n = 1) {
      return this.down(-n)
    }

    move(right = 0, down = 0) {
      this.right(right).down(down)
    }
  }
}

class Cursor {
  row: number = 0
  col: number = 0
  constructor(row: number, col: number) {
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
  }
  down(n: number): Navigation<never> {
    return new CursorNext(this.row + n, this.col)
  }

  right(n: number): Navigation<never> {
    return new CursorNext(this.row, this.col + n)
  }
}

const CursorNext = Navigable(Cursor)
// or
const CursorNext = Navigable<never, typeof Cursor>(Cursor)
```

<sup>([Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gwgewHYGdgCcCuBjYD0A8AKlALxQDeAvgHxlRIQDuUAFAHScCG6A5igC4oXJCADaAXQCUZOkQBQ8gJZJgEdADMu2aADkuANyW8uwJcmJ0K8qFExhWSIUkwBbAEbqpQ-UZNmLIhobKAATBCYkR2c3T3RvKF9jU3MkSxCAGwgNYGiGWK8fQ2SAtKCQ9GMAC1ynfI9CxOL-VPSqRVBIKABZBAMudyzLemtbSt4aoTyXBvjZJr8UwODbcMipupm4mVI6JJbl+Xb5DUwkXFSF5MGIYgAaKCIAIS4UaAgADzUkUJRYRFQGBweEIvX6N0sNBorBebyEz1eEBkoyg6AgwEw6CQUGwGVef0+31+UFh0CUrjAWVcEFUf32SzKVhCtiyOUc9AAjMjmbZUejMdjgFUlCh2OMaqwALRIKQ8468uwObHkLmUHljflYqBCkXsNZRaWyhXy3muPoQVji4D0AAMD31tu5CtsOtFVst1WAUj1ESi+qNvPatnax1x+KgcExKHwarGERis1tIWwCAyCbiSdsKcBWFw+Et8fqcQeKbTRa8sd5rrFEXo6AiAG4edXS-RS03gyF9dMCvEiotSgRGAZ1EyFWiMVrGCxI+ho+hdITWNX6ywANQMB4t1MBk3uza9hL0wfD0eVjWT7HTiNR-CLr7L4VuiJbp-sVsbmUhEOKbNoG9znehL0PSNysLO85SEAA))</sup>

Notice I've removed the `GConstructor` from the `Movable` type and used it only in the type requirement for `TBase`, I've renamed the function and made the class anonymous for less ambiguity, and instantiated `T` to `never` since it is use nowhere and could be completely omitted.

Comment: I have a question on the return value of down/right, here we return `new CursorNext`, what if subclass of Cursor diverges ie, `Flyable(Cursor)` `Fruitful(Navigable(Cursor))`, what should I return then?

Comment: Another thing I found is down/right should not return type of `Navigation` since it lost other function references to Cursor itself. Say if I want to `new Cursor(1,2).down().equals(new Cursor(2,2))`, TS won't know `equals` exists.

Comment: You can use `return new this.constructor(…)`, but I don't think you can properly type that.